# Python3 subprocess.check_output catch exception without printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, subprocess

I'm working on using subprocess.check_output to call ping command and get some output. The script will catch the wrong domain name. However, the output of the ping command will always print out on its own. When there's no exception, the output will not print out on its own.

```
hostname = "somewrongdomain.com"  # This domain will not connect
try:
    response = (subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c 1", self.hostname]).decode("utf-8")
    print(response)

except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    ping_rating = 0

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    ping_rating = 0

#do something else
```

The output I'm getting:

```
$ python3 test.py
ping: sendto: No route to host
```

Is there any way to NOT print the output(*ping: sendto: No route to host*) when the exception is caught?

Answer (score 2):

As [written in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) `subprocess.check_output` only captures `STDOUT`.

> To also capture standard error in the result, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```